# Unable to right-click in Unity window manager

Tags: unity, mouse, touchpad, button

I cannot right-click in Unity window manager in a fresh install of Ubuntu 21.10.

I have a new Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 which includes a touchpad alone, with no buttons. In gnome display manager (chosen from lightdm) I can two-finger-tap the touchpad to generate the equivalent of a right click. In Unity window manager two-finger-tap sadly does nothing.

My understanding is that installing the gnome-tweak-tool package allows the desired right-click behaviour to be changed in gnome, but I cannot find any workaround in Unity.

Also alarmingly, when I type into the dash in Unity no applications are found, which makes it more complicated to e.g. open a terminal, though again there's no problem in gdm.

Is it possible I need to install some packages beyond unity-session?

Relevant system info:

```
Ubuntu 21.10
Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5
unity-session 40.1.1-1ubuntu1
gdm3 41-rc-0ubuntu2
```